# Посимвольное чтение файла в массив. Почему не считываются некоторые символы?

Tags: c++, файлы, шифрование

Программа для шифрования и расшифрования файлов.

Вот код.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <fstream.h>  
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop 

#include "Unit1.h" 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init) 
#pragma resource "*.dfm" 
TForm1 *Form1; 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) 
        : TForm(Owner) 
{  
}  
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)  
{  
if (OpenDialog1->Execute() ) 
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromFile (OpenDialog1->FileName) ; 

} 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn2Click(TObject *Sender)  
{  
  int q=0;  
  char ch;  
  char mas1[8];  
  char mas2[8];
  char mas3[8]; 

  char gam[8] = {'П', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'б', 'я', 'Y', 'v'};
  ifstream infile(OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str());  
  ofstream outfile("Ofile.txt"); 
  while(!infile.eof())  
  {  
    ++q;  
    int i;  

    for(i=0; i<8; ++i) 
    {  
      infile.get(ch);  
      if(!infile.eof())  
      { 
        mas2[i]=ch; 
      }  
      else  
        break;  
    }  

    if(q==1) 
    { 
      for(int j=0; j<i; ++j) 
      {  
        mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j];  
        outfile.put(mas3[j]);  
      }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      for(int c=0; c<i; ++c) 
      {  
        mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
        outfile.put(mas3[c]);  
      }  
    }  
    for(int w=0; w<i; ++w) 
    {  
      mas1[w] = mas3[w]; 
    }  
  }  
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn3Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
  int q=0;  
  char ch;  
  char mas1[8];  
  char mas2[8];  
  char mas3[8];  
  char gam[8] = {'П', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'б', 'я', 'Y', 'v'}; 
  ifstream infile(OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str());  
  ofstream outfile("File.txt");  
  while(!infile.eof()) 
  {  
    ++q; 
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<8; ++i)  
    { 
      infile.get(ch); 
      if(!infile.eof())  
      {  
        mas2[i]=ch;  
      }  
      else  
        break;  
    }  

    if(q==1)  
    {  
      for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)  
      {
        mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j]; 
        outfile.put(mas3[j]);
      }  
    } 
    else  
    { 
      for(int c=0; c<i; ++c) 
      { 
        mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];  
        outfile.put(mas3[c]);  
      }  
    }  
    for(int w=0; w<i; ++w)  
    {  
      mas1[w] = mas2[w]; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

При зашифровании файла `.rtf` все проходит без ошибок. Зашифрованный файл по весу равен исходному. Но при расшифровании, а именно посимвольном чтении.

```
for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
  infile.get(ch);
  if(!infile.eof())
  {
    mas2[i]=ch;
  }
```

Программа игнорирует некоторые символы и файл получается поврежденным. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: ну и зачем неуважительно относится к сообществу? вам что здесь помойка?

Comment: Я правильнее задал вопрос. Вот и все

Comment: зачем дубль делать да и еще второй раз в убогом виде?

Comment: я здесь только второй день и мало что освоил. Извините за неудобства